# uploading metadata using React

Tags: solana-program, metaplex, metadata

Facing an issue while uploading the metadata from React.

```
  const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection)
    .use(walletAdapterIdentity(wallet.adapter))
    .use(
      bundlrStorage({
        address: "https://devnet.bundlr.network",
        providerUrl: "https://api.devnet.solana.com",
        timeout: 60000,
      })
    );
```

**Error:**
process is not defined

Answer (score 1):

The error likely means that you're using node.js code in a browser, since `process` exists in node, but not browser.

There exist compatibility shims like https://www.npmjs.com/package/process to get access to some of the `process` functions in browser, so you may want to integrate that in your project.